# send notification when you finish executing a script in R

Tags: r

I need to send a notification when I finish processing a predictions I am making,

I have an idea to create an ETL process that validates a value. This value would be written in DB 1 = if the process ends, 0 = the process has not finished. When the prediction ends, it should trigger a sending of an email, but I don't know if it is the best strategy.

Does anyone have other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try using mailR package for sending an e-mail.

So if that doesn't work, you can use a combination of the

```
system()
```

command and the answer from this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, I do not have the permissions in the firewall, or the corporate gmail account for this, is it possible to do this in another way? that is the challenge

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu